# Feathers Js Learning

Tags: feathersjs

Can anyone help to find some best tutorials for Feathers JS. I have already gone thriugh their official documentations. But still is not able to completely follow their documentation. I was searching for some tutorials then. I found one in Udemy but it is of Espaniol. So please let me know if any tutorials or online courses available for Feathers JS.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

The [awesome FeathersJS](https://github.com/feathersjs/awesome-feathersjs/) site and [feathersresources.dev](https://feathersresources.dev/) have a large number of links to examples, tutorials and more. There are also [many ways to get help](https://docs.feathersjs.com/help/) including the [Slack channel to ask questions](http://slack.feathersjs.com/).